# what is this i have big problem in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, plugins, cmake

[it is my plugins  sdk and i dont know what is cmake it is important](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZVTd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZVTd.png)
There is an error in vs code android studio. I get an error in every emulator. The error I get in vs code is Exception: Build process failed.
do you have any idea and vs code gave an error solution and a page called cmake came out, what does it do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UJB5.png)

Comment: I suggest you to delete everything and follow some "How to install flutter" guides.

Comment: The shape of the question is not so good... Please, read [ask] and edit the question post accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to resolve flutter doctor issue? can you include `flutter doctor -v` command output?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to reinstall the flutter SDK in your laptop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).